# /img/checkbox_checked.gif D'ont render properly on Mobile

Tags: visualforce, mobile

/img/checkbox_checked.gif do not render properly in preview mode on mobile salesforce 1[image]

```
<div style="width:99%;border:2px solid #000000;margin: 3px;  font-family:Calibri (Body);letter-spacing:2px;font-size:10px;padding:3px;"> 
            <apex:form >  

                <img src="{!$Resource.image_2}" style="height: 15px"  /><span style="font-style:normal;"> <b>NATURE DES LOCAUX </b></span><br/>
                <em style="padding:0px 5px;font-style:normal;">J’atteste que les travaux à réaliser portent sur un immeuble achevé depuis plus de deux ans à la date de commencement des travaux et
                    affecté à l’habitation à l’issue de ces travaux :</em><br/>
                <img src="/img/checkbox_checked.gif" style="background-color:white;"/>maison ou immeuble individuel <img src="/img/checkbox_unchecked.gif" style="background-color: white;"/> immeuble collectif<img src="/img/checkbox_unchecked.gif"/>appartement individuel<br/>
                <img src="/img/checkbox_unchecked.gif"/>autre (précisez la nature du local à usage d’habitation) ……………………………………………………………………
                Les travaux sont réalisés dans :<br/>
                <img src="/img/checkbox_checked.gif"/>un local affecté exclusivement ou principalement à l’habitation<br/>
                <img src="/img/checkbox_unchecked.gif"/>des pièces affectées exclusivement à l’habitation situées dans un local affecté pour moins de 50 % à cet usage<br/>
                <img src="/img/checkbox_unchecked.gif"/>des parties communes de locaux affectés exclusivement ou principalement à l’habitation dans une proportion de (……………….)
                millièmes de l’immeuble<br/>
                <img src="/img/checkbox_unchecked.gif"/>un local antérieurement affecté à un usage autre que d’habitation et transformé à cet usage<br/>
                Adresse<sup>2</sup>
                :………………………………………………Commune………………………………..Code postal :………<br/>
                dont je suis :&nbsp; &nbsp;<img src="/img/checkbox_unchecked.gif"/> 
                propriétaire &nbsp; &nbsp; <img src="/img/checkbox_unchecked.gif"/>  &nbsp; &nbsp;locataire <img src="/img/checkbox_unchecked.gif"/>autre (précisez votre qualité) :………………………………<br/>

            </apex:form>

        </div>
```